# js setTimeout recursion return-continue

Tags: javascript, c++, recursion, return, settimeout

I'll use this simple maze-solver program written in C for example of what i need in javascript:

```
int is_free_place(int x,int y) {
 char ch[2];
 if(x<1||x>80||y<1||y>20)
  return 0;
 gettext(x,y,x,y,ch);
 return ch[0]==32; // X or space
}
int solve(int x, int y, int x_end,int y_end) {
 int ans=0;
 if(kbhit()) efn();
 gotoxy(x,y);
 putchar('.');
 delay(DELAY_TIME);
 if(x==x_end&&y==y_end)
  return 1;
 if(is_free_place(x-1,y))
  ans=solve(x-1,y,x_end,y_end);      //// <<<<< recursion starts here
 if(ans==0&&is_free_place(x+1,y))    //// can't continue to here if using setTimeout
  ans=solve(x+1,y,x_end,y_end);      //// because ans is not set
 if(ans==0&&is_free_place(x,y-1))
  ans=solve(x,y-1,x_end,y_end);
 if(ans==0&&is_free_place(x,y+1))
  ans=solve(x,y+1,x_end,y_end);
 if(ans==0){
  gotoxy(x,y);
  putchar(' ');
  delay(DELAY_TIME);
 }
 return ans;
}
void main(){
 clrscr();
 efn(); // reads maze from file, shows menu, calls solve()
}
```

I'm trying to do a similar recursion in javascript, but the browser freezes until the code is done and what i need is a slow animation of the progress with the option to pause and change stuff. So i tried using setTimeout, but i can't figure out the algorithm for when the function "returns" and code continues from the recursion call...
(setTimeout continues right away and does not wait for function return )

[update]
is there a way to do this using yield, and not using stack?

Comment: We're not going to write all the JS for you. Show us what you've got (hopefully more readable than the C version).

Comment: I don't need all the C code in JS ;)
I just need the idea for the return part (i know that setTimeout returns id, i'm talking about the return of the function that setTimeout calls) so i can do a different, much bigger project...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's going to be a bit non-trivial to write this as something you can use with setTimeout, especially since, as written, you *need to get the result of your recursive invocations*.   I think the easiest way to handle something like this is would have to use some sort of promise infrastructure as with dojo and jQuery (or write it yourself).  I'd go into more detail but I can't work on this further at the moment.  One hint:  I think jQuery's `pipe` method would do wonders here.

The other options that come to mind is to rewrite it to use a stack which would save the ans variable and maybe something signifying what part of the current function invocation you would need to go back to.

Comment: the "messy" solution i came up with is indeed using a stack, to which i add the local variables before calling the setTimeout, and i divided the function to "steps". it works for the maze solver, but it is too confusing to keep using this method, i need the true recursion =)

Answer (score 1):

`setTimeout` only runs once.  It's return value is the timeout itself.

```
var timeout = setTimeout(function () { console.log( "hi" ) }, 1000);
// timeout == some id
```

This allows you to clear the timeout if you choose to do so with the `clearTimeout` method

You can create a game loop using a recursive `setTimeout` loop.

```
setTimeout(function call() {
     // Do code
     //...     
     setTimeout( call, 1000 / 60 ); // loop
}, 1000 / 60 ) // 60 fps
```

Answer (score 0):

Here is an javascript example how to use `setTimeout` and how to clear it by using `clearTimeout`.

```
<html>
<head>
<script type="text/javascript">
var c=0;
var t;
var timer_is_on=0;

function timedCount()
  {
  document.getElementById('txt').value=c;
  c=c+1;
  t=setTimeout("timedCount()",1000);
  }

function doTimer()
  {
  if (!timer_is_on)
    {
    timer_is_on=1;
    timedCount();
    }
  }

function stopCount()
  {
  clearTimeout(t);
  timer_is_on=0;
  }
</script>
</head>
<body>

<form>
<input type="button" value="Start count!" onclick="doTimer()" />
<input type="text" id="txt" />
<input type="button" value="Stop count!" onclick="stopCount()" />
</form>

</body>
</html>
```

It is taken from [here.](http://www.w3schools.com/jsref/met_win_cleartimeout.asp)

Comment: thenx, i know all that, and that is not what i need. i need to work with the return of the function that is inside the setTimeout...

Comment: @Antonimo you can't return anything (usefully, anyway) from the callback passed to `setTimeout`.

Comment: @MattBall right, that is why i'm trying to come up with a workaround to get similar results of the example C code that i gave.

Answer (score -1):

I think setInterval will do the job: [setInterval](http://www.w3schools.com/jsref/met_win_setinterval.asp)

```
  var int = setInterval(clock,1000);

  function clock()
  {
     var d=new Date();
     var t=d.toLocaleTimeString();
     document.getElementById("clock").value=t;
  }
```

Comment: this is a loop, not a recursion